# Incorrect line position with HTML Canvas when lineWidth is not set to 1

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

```
  function drawModule() {
    const lineWidth = 1
    context.lineWidth = lineWidth
    context.translate(0.5, 0.5)

    for (let k = 0; k < self.geometryParsed.length; k++) {
      const geometry = self.geometryParsed[k].geom
      const type = self.geometryParsed[k].typ

      context.beginPath()
      context.strokeStyle = self.unitMixTable[type]
      context.moveTo(
        Math.round(geometry[0].x),
        Math.round(geometry[0].y)
      )
      for (let i = 1; i < geometry.length; i++) {
        context.lineTo(
          Math.round(geometry[i].x),
          Math.round(geometry[i].y)
        )
        context.stroke()
      }
      context.closePath()
      context.fillStyle = 'white'
      context.fill()
    }
    context.translate(-0.5, -0.5)
  }
```

Here is the code I use for drawing some polygons in the canvas, and it works as expected without problem. But when the lineWidth is 2, for example, the positions and opacity of the lines are slightly distorted.

picture of the result:

lineWidth = 1
[image]

lineWidth = 2
[image]

As you can see in red circle of the figure when lineWidth is 2, the lines are not aligned even if they share same x point. And in the rightmost rectange of each group, colors of the lines are not same.

What might the problem be? is there any point am I missing? thanks in advance!

reproduce: https://codepen.io/coldsewoo/pen/mdeZBev

Comment: You got some `Math.round(` in your code are you sure they share the same point

Comment: @HelderSepulveda / It should be, the left and right rects has exacty same x coordinates in the array. Tried to remove all the Math.round things in the code, nothing changed

Comment: @HelderSepulveda / Sorry with my poor English, I meant they are exactly same. https://codepen.io/coldsewoo/pen/mdeZBev <-- reproduce

Comment: Remove the final translate(-.5,-.5), that hacks works only for lineWidth 1.

Comment: @Kaiido your [duplicate] does not address the issue with the alignment

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes it does, it clearly says that strokes extend on both ways of the coordinates, unlike filling. So that explains how filling over a stroke will cover half of that stroke and why the smaller rects didn't cover correctly the neighbors strokes.

Comment: Sorry @Kaiido but that is not the alignment issue presented on the image by Coldsewoo, the problem there is the use of fill

Comment: @HelderSepulveda "that explains how filling over a stroke will cover half of that stroke"

Comment: @Kaiido on that question or the answer there is no mention of fill anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fill is the root cause of your problems

```js
const geometryParsed = [
  {
    geom: [{ x:78, y:132 }, { x:59, y:132 }, { x:59, y:183 }, { x:78, y:183 }, { x:78, y:132 }]
  },
  {
    geom: [{ x:97, y:132 }, { x:78, y:132 }, { x:78, y:166 }, { x:97, y:166 }, { x:97, y:132 }]
  },
];

const canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canv.getContext("2d");

context.translate(-50, -100)
context.lineWidth = 2;
for (let k = 0; k < geometryParsed.length; k++) {
  const geometry = geometryParsed[k].geom;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(geometry[0].x, geometry[0].y);
  for (let i = 1; i < geometry.length; i++) {
    context.lineTo(geometry[i].x, geometry[i].y);    
  }
  context.stroke();
}

context.translate(80, 0)
context.lineWidth = 4;
for (let k = 0; k < geometryParsed.length; k++) {
  const geometry = geometryParsed[k].geom;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(geometry[0].x, geometry[0].y);
  for (let i = 1; i < geometry.length; i++) {
    context.lineTo(geometry[i].x, geometry[i].y);
  }
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="476px" height="170px"></canvas>
```